# Why is const MyClass const* not valid?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am rather new in C++ and I get confused when trying to read this kind of prototypes.

This prototype **"builds"** in **Visual Studio 2012** (in a **Native C++ Static library**, not C++/CLI), although it doesn't make the pointer constant.
I noticed it throws a warning, which I didn't see at first.

**C++ Visual Studio 2012**

```
     int intTest =3;
     int intTest2 = 5;
     const int const* pointerTest = &intTest;
     pointerTest = &intTest2; //This works

     const int* const pointerTest2 = &intTest;
     pointerTest2 = &intTest2; //This doesn't build because the pointer is constant.
```

I realized of my mistake because when I was trying to build this code in Linux (**Eclipse with GCC 4.6.3**) it throws an error:

> duplicate 'const'

I wrote this instead of **const MyClass* const** by mistake, but I didn't notice it because Visual Studio didn't throw an error.

Why is this syntax wrong? I didn't write it on purpose but I would like to understand.

Comment: http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/17/continental-const-placement/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` decorates the term to its left, unless it's the left-most, then it decorates the term to its right.

Rewrite your declaration using above rule is

```
int const const* pointerTest = &intTest;
```

You should write:

```
const int * const pointerTest = &intTest;
```

Or stick to the right-const style and won't get puzzled:

```
int const * const * const * const someEvilVariable = foo();
```

Comment: So from "int const const* pointerTest = &intTest;" it means that i wrote: "[int const const]* pointerTest = &intTest;" A pointer to "int const const"? Now that makes sense! Wish Visual Studio would throw error like GCC though.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
 const int const* pointerTest = &intTest;
```

qualifier const was simply duplicated. It is equivalent to

```
 const int * pointerTest = &intTest;
```

or

```
 int const* pointerTest = &intTest;
```

Here a pointer yo a constant data is being defined. The pointer itself is not a constant.

In this statement

```
const int* const pointerTest2 = &intTest;
```

you defined the pointer itself as a constant. It may be initialized only when it is defined and may not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

`const MyClass *` and `MyClass const *` both declare a pointer to const data, so both `const`s immediately either side of MyClass are doing the exact same thing, hence the warning.

One technique for understanding what's been declared is to read the declaration from right to left e.g.

```
MyClass const * const pointerTest = &intTest; //a const pointer to const data of type MyClass
```

However, you can place the qualifier either side immediately next to the class name, like so:

```
const MyClass * const pointerTest = &intTest; //a const pointer to data that is const.
```

Other possible declarations:

```
const MyClass * pointerTest = &intTest; //a non-const pointer to const data.
MyClass * const pointerTest = &intTest; //a const pointer to non-const data.
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter if the `const` come before or after the `type` (`int`).

Therefore

```
const int const* pointerTest
```

translates into

```
const int* pointerTest
```

since putting `const` twice do nothing.

What is matter is the order of `const` and `*`, so in you case:

-the first is a `pointer` to `const int`:

```
const int const* pointerTest = &intTest;
```

-and the second is a `const pointer` to `const int`: (since the `const` comes after the `*`)

```
const int* const pointerTest2 = &intTest;
```

therefore you can't change the pointer and get an error.